# workaround for missing --script in ipython notebook 3.0.0-dev

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've been using automaticall saved scripts beside `.ipynb` files as a convenient way to write modules using ipython notebook. I updated to the head version today, and it seems the `--script` functionality has been removed.

Is there a way to obtain that functionality (automatically on save) with the latest ipython?
Running `ipython notebook` gives me a message telling me that it's been removed, and suggests doing

```
ipython nbconvert --to python [notebook]
```

To make that work automaticaly, I'd have to trigger it on each save - is there an easy way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a workaround, but the `--script` functionality was still present in release 2.3.0 (if you're running from a live git repo, you can checkout tag 'rel-2.3.0').